# plot estimates with 95%CI from lmer model

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, sjplot

I need help in plotting the estimates and 95% CI from Lmer model, i am using *plot_model* from *sjplot* function.

```r
library(lme4)       # linear mixed-effects models
library(lmerTest)   # test for linear mixed-effects models
library(gtsummary)
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

names(trajectories)
library(tidyverse)


str(trajectories$yr_qun)

trajectories <- trajectories %>% 
  mutate(yr_qun = yr_qun %>%
           fct_relevel("2001_low","2001_medium", "2001_high",
                       "2002_low","2002_medium", "2002_high",
                       "2003_low","2003_medium", "2003_high",
                       "2004_low","2004_medium", "2004_high",
                       "2005_low","2005_medium", "2005_high",
                       "2006_low","2006_medium", "2006_high",
                       "2007_low","2007_medium", "2007_high",
                       "2008_low","2008_medium", "2008_high",
                       "2009_low","2009_medium", "2009_high",
                       "2010_low","2010_medium", "2010_high"))

m1 <- lmer(distance ~ yr_qun + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
summary(m1)

p <- plot_model(m1, order.terms = rev(1:29)) + coord_cartesian() 
p
```

i would like to have a plot as shown in the following picture

[image]

here is dummy data

```
dput(trajectories)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L), distance = c(15, 
20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 
21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 
25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 
21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 21, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 
23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 
24, 15, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 24, 25.5, 20.5, 24), age = c(8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L), 
    Quintile = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L), levels = c("Q1", "Q2", 
    "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), yr_qun = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 27L, 30L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 
    15L, 17L, 20L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
    19L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 
    27L, 29L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 
    2L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 
    23L, 25L, 30L, 10L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 1L, 4L, 
    8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 
    17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
    24L, 25L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 
    30L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 
    31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 
    10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 
    17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 
    24L, 25L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 
    30L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 30L), levels = c("2001_low", 
    "2001_medium", "2001_high", "2002_low", "2002_medium", "2002_high", 
    "2003_low", "2003_medium", "2003_high", "2004_low", "2004_medium", 
    "2004_high", "2005_low", "2005_medium", "2005_high", "2006_low", 
    "2006_medium", "2006_high", "2007_low", "2007_medium", "2007_high", 
    "2008_low", "2008_medium", "2008_high", "2009_low", "2009_medium", 
    "2009_high", "2010_low", "2010_medium", "2010_high", ""), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-183L))
```

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You could extract estimate and 95% CI, then create a data.frame for a plot.
Next, `year` and `class` was extracted from `yr_qun~`, using `str_extract()`.

```r
library(lmerTest)   # test for linear mixed-effects models
library(gtsummary)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

m1 <- lmer(distance ~ yr_qun + (1 | id), data = trajectories)
ci <- as.data.frame(confint(m1))
m1_estimate <- summary(m1)$coefficients[2:length(unique(trajectories$yr_qun)),1]
target <- setdiff(intersect(rownames(ci),rownames(summary(m1)$coefficients)),"(Intercept)")
m1_ci <- ci[target,]

result <- tibble(name = names(m1_estimate), 
                est = as.numeric(m1_estimate), 
                ci_lower = as.numeric(m1_ci[,1]),
                ci_upper = as.numeric(m1_ci[,2]))

result <- result |> 
  filter(name != "yr_qun") |> 
  mutate(year = str_extract(name,"[:digit:]+"),
         class = str_extract(name, "[:alpha:]+$"))

result |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=est, color = class, group=class))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper),
                alpha=.5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: My pleasure. If you like the answer, please accept it :)

Comment: sure I'll accept it shortly. just running on real data.

Comment: @ Y H Jang, i want to clarify the dimension in the coefficients in m1_estimate <- summary(m1)$coefficients[2:31,1], in my real data i have 30 levels in variable so i changed to this m1_estimate <- summary(m1)$coefficients[2:30,1], but i get an error of incorrect number of dimensions. any help would be highly appreciated. thank you

Comment: I see. How about `summary(m1)$coefficients[2:length(unique(trajectories$yr_qun)
),1]`? Then you don't have to manually set the index

Comment: thanks that worked. thank you. moving ahead with code

Comment: got some connection issues so unable to run the rest of the code. so I'll update you once my connection to real data is restored. thanks for all your help.

Comment: hi got stuck again with code result <- tibble(name = names(m1_estimate), 
                est = as.numeric(m1_estimate), 
                ci_lower = as.numeric(m1_ci[,1]),
                ci_upper = as.numeric(m1_ci[,2]))
when i run this code, i get an error of  Error in tibble()  tibble columns must have compatible sizes. size 145: existing data.  size29: column 'ci_lower'. only values of size one are recycled. Backtrace: 1.tibble::tibble(...)

Comment: I edited the answer. Check this out.

Comment: many thanks for the prompt help and edit. i updated my code with new ci, target and m1_ci but still get the same error i get an error of Error in tibble() tibble columns must have compatible sizes. size 145: existing data. size30: column 'ci_lower'. only values of size one are recycled. Backtrace: 1.tibble::tibble(...)

Comment: Seems like the length of data problem. Unfortunately, I couldn't help you without your real data.

Comment: thank you much for all your help. Due to sensitivety of the data even I don't have full access to data. I ll try to figure out.

Comment: @ YH Jang, I am trying to figure out where 145: existing data comes from. I checked the size for both m1_estimate and ci_lower used in Tibble, both have the same size of 29. how should i figure it out.

Comment: Have you check the `m1_estimate`? I guess the error is to do with the estimate. What you only need in `summary(m1)` is the `Estimate` column.  145 means maybe you are binding all `summary(m1)` components (i.e., not only `Estimate` but `std.error`, `df`, `t value`, and `p`)

Comment: @ YH Jang, you are right. the 145 figure was binding all components. I modified the code as below. result <- tibble(name = names(m1_estimate[,1]), 
                est = as.numeric(m1_estimate[,1]), 
                ci_lower = as.numeric(m1_ci[,1]),
                ci_upper = as.numeric(m1_ci[,2]))

Comment: thanks it worked. I realize regression output changed the variable label in the summary output. thought it is a factor variable and the same categories as in the variable yr_qun above (see above screenshot). what should I do so my regression output doesn't change the labels?

Comment: i need your help to extract some info from the names variable in the above codes for extracting year and class from yr_qun~, using str_extract(). in the real data, the the text in names column is "intrcn.yr.highexposurecat2_revised2013 low exposure
"Some examples of text are attached in the picture above. I have to extract the last two (low exposure or high exposure) or one word ( middle)  and second I want to extract the year from this mutate(year = str_extract(name,"[:digit:]+"),
class = str_extract(name, "[:alpha:]+$")). any help much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you ask as another question? It's quite hard to answer by your comments. Plus asking multiple questions is not allowed in stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks YH Jang, i asked separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206568/extracting-last-word-and-year-using-str-extract-in-r

Comment: I just answered to your new question. And I would appreciate if you accept the answer of this question.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help. have a wonderful day ahead

Comment: how can i add asteric to estimates in the plot?