# extracting last word and year using str_extract in r

Tags: ggplot2, statistics

I need help extracting the last word and year using *str_extract* from the name column in a data frame. In the following code in mutate section for the year, I would like to extract the year (2015/2017/2013 or so). while for the class I would like to extract the last word (low/middle/high).

```r
result <- result |> 
  filter(name != "yr_qun") |> 
  mutate(year = str_extract(name,"[:digit:]+"),
         class = str_extract(name, "[:alpha:]+$"))
```

here is my dummy data

```r
dput(extract)
structure(list(names = c("intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2013 middle", 
"intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2014 middle", "intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2015 middle", 
"intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2009 middle", "intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2007 middle", 
"intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2010 middle", "intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2013 low", 
"intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2014 low", "intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2015 low", 
"intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2017 high", "intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2007 high", 
"intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2010 high")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `str_extract()`, and `str_split()`.

```
temp |> 
  mutate(year = str_extract(names, "[:digit:]{4}"),
         class = str_split(names, pattern = " ", n=2, simplify = T)[,2])
```

**output**

```
  names                                 year  class 
   <chr>                                 <chr> <chr> 
 1 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2013 middle 2013  middle
 2 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2014 middle 2014  middle
 3 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2015 middle 2015  middle
 4 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2009 middle 2009  middle
 5 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2007 middle 2007  middle
 6 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2010 middle 2010  middle
 7 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2013 low    2013  low   
 8 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2014 low    2014  low   
 9 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2015 low    2015  low   
10 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2017 high   2017  high  
11 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2007 high   2007  high  
12 intrcn.yr.highcat2_revised2010 high   2010  high
```

Comment: Jang, thanks for your help. the year is extracted but my class variable is empty using this code result <- result |> 
  filter(name != "yr_qun") |> 
  mutate(year = str_extract(name,"[:digit:]{4}"),
         class = str_split(name, pattern = " ",2, simplify = T)[,2])

Comment: But the code works for `extract`. Is the name of `result` same as that of `extract`?

Comment: yes, it is.   result <- result |> 
  filter(name != "yr_qun") |> 
  mutate(year = str_extract(name,"[:digit:]{4}"),
         class = str_split(name, pattern = " ",2, simplify = T)[,2])

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not help you because I can't access to your `result`. When it comes to `[,2]`, the `name` would be spliced into two, (e.g., `~revised2013`, and `middle`). Please double-check the `name`.